# How do I send an array with fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to send an array using fetch that looks like this:

```
{"cards":[[189,2],[211,2],[238,2],[778,2],[985,2],[1008,2],[1073,2],[1171,2],[48886,2],[49161,2],[49164,2],[49184,1],[49356,2],[50372,2],[51722,1],[52422,2]],"heroes":[1066],"format":2}
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
 getCardsForDeck = deck => {
    var stringifiedDeck = JSON.stringify(deck);
    console.log("stringifiedDeck:" + stringifiedDeck);
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/getCardsForDeck`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: stringifiedDeck
    })
      .then(cards => cards.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ cards: res.cards }));
  };
```

I am getting an error though:

```
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

How do I send this data if not with JSON.stringify() or do I have to edit the data to remove the brackets?

Upon checking the api in the network tab it gives me this:

```
     SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
[0]     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
[0]     at parse (C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
[0]     at C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
[0]     at invokeCallback (C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
[0]     at done (C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
[0]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[0] SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
[0]     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
[0]     at parse (C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
[0]     at C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
[0]     at invokeCallback (C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
[0]     at done (C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\User\projects\webapp\deck-editor\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
[0]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: This error message suggests that what you get is most likely *not* JSON. And since it starts with `<` then what usually happens is you get an error *page*, so that is HTML for, say, a 404 page or a 500 or something like that. Examine the response and you should see the response HTML

Comment: Does `http://localhost:3001/api/getCardsForDeck` respond by echoing what you PUT back to you? Your code seems to assume it will. Normally it would send its *own* response, which may be in JSON, or text, or HTML...

Comment: your api function might be outputting errors: https://www.kevinleary.net/syntax-error-unexpected-token-json-position-0/

Comment: You might need to specify the type of data returned, e.g. API is returning XML and you want JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be expecting `http://localhost:3001/api/getCardsForDeck` to send JSON **back** after you send JSON **to** it. Most likely it's responding with HTML, not JSON.

There are two other errors in that code:

1. You need to say what you're sending, since it's not the default URI-encoded data:

   ```
   fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/getCardsForDeck`, {
     method: "PUT",
     body: stringifiedDeck,
     headers: {                              // ***
       "Content-Type": "application/json"    // ***
     }                                       // ***
   })
   ```
2. You need to check the status of the response. (*Everyone* misses this out.) The simplest way is to check the `ok` flag on the response:

   ```
   fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/getCardsForDeck`, {
     method: "PUT",
     body: stringifiedDeck,
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     }
   })
   .then(response => {
     if (!response.ok) {                                  // ***
       throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);  // ***
     }                                                    // ***
     // ...use `response.json`, `response.text`, etc. here
   })
   .catch(error => {
     // ...handle/report error
   });
   ```

Comment: This call in #2 would go before any other calls correct? It would be the first 'then'?

Comment: Actually, I understand now, making changes now!

Comment: @davidahines - That's right, yes. Typically at the end of that first `then` you'd have `return response.json();` (if you were expecting JSON) or `return response.text();` (if you were expecting text), etc., where I have "use `response.json`, `response.text, etc. here" above, and then another `then` to actually use the data.

Comment: Should I still be stringifying it if I am telling it I am sending json?

Comment: @davidahines - Yes, because JSON is, by definition, text. (So if you're working in JavaScript code, and not working with a *string*, you're not working with JSON.) If you didn't use `JSON.stringify`, it wouldn't be JSON, it'd be an object. (That doesn't prevent lots of libs from converting to JSON *for* you, but I'm 99% sure `fetch` won't. :-) )

Comment: After setting this it was easy to track down the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue today but I wanna transfer the list to backend rather than receive the correct error. The solution is really simple I cannot believe I stuck several hours.

My solution is following:

```
const response = await fetch(SERVER_URL + `/api/studyPlan/${plan.userid}`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  credentials: "include",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    plan: planlist,
  }),
});
```

In the list `planlist` is the array. We could send this list as the value and  send to backend.
Then in backend, use `req.body.plan` directly to get information.

Hope it helps